# simulate browser behaviour via Python (javascript, DOM)

Tags: javascript, python, dom, browser, simulation

Is it possible to simulate a browser via Python?

Example:

There are actions on a website, that can be just done with javascript. Is it also possible, to load such a website (with executing all its javascript, http requests, DOM) in python and then run custom javascript on it, after DOM is built?
Like the behaviour of a lightweight browser, just without all graphical rendering stuff.

Comment: Maybe you can try selenium with PhantomJS!?

Comment: I'm using selenium + chromedriver for this, works amazing!