# Execute method javascript with simulate browser

Tags: javascript, testing, dom, browser

I would like to script my example (it's an idea example it's not for this site)

Exemple (no real!) :

1. I open browser
2. I open this url : https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:5752028
3. I open console developper
4. I launch a javascript method to load in the DOM for example downloadFile() (it does not really exist on this site it is to image or more real : document.getElementsByTagName('button')[16].click() )
5. a file download starts (as if I clicked on a direct download link)
6. Save this file started

Any idea if is possible ? i thinks yes for unit test javascript no ?

Thx

No idea why i can do that..No limits language

Same :
[simulate browser behaviour via Python (javascript, DOM)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39187340/simulate-browser-behaviour-via-python-javascript-dom) with no response :(

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: The question you linked *has* a response. While not posted as an answer, the comment has the solution: use a browser automation library such as selenium or playwright.